# Reclassifying table to get values per cell using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, reclassify

I reclassified a utilization distribution (space use; raster) map for an animal with an electronic transmitter, so that its original values fall within three classes: 0-2. When I open its attribute table, it shows me a summary table of the number of cells per category. However, I am interested in the reclassified value for each grid cell within my study area.

Is there a way to do this?

A google search was unhelpful, perhaps because I am not specific enough it the problem formulation. What I am looking for is an attribute table that at least shows the grid cell ID and its corresponding value for all grid cells considered.

Comment: Can't you simply look at the original raster to identify the original value before you reclassified it into 0 to 2?

Comment: No raster format has an attribute table of each cell and their value as you could potentially have billions of rows for very large rasters. The only way is to convert it to a point dataset of billions of points...

Comment: To provide a little more information: my raster is 180 grid cells of 1 km^2 each (12x15), and i have 1 value per cell for 180 total so it's not that bad. The original raster's attribute table is greyed out, i cannot open it. It is also not informative since i need to work with the reclassified data.

Comment: Is the original raster of type float? Only integer rasters can have an attribute table.

Comment: Yes, the original raster has pixel type = "floating point".

Comment: What I ended up doing is overlay a fishnet on the reclassified raster, and then manually transfer the information to excel. It's a pain in the ass, especially with multiple datasets, and the method is error prone, but with careful double checking i was able to do get what i needed. Wish there was an easy way in ArcMap to do this, i don't understand why it's useful to show a summarized attribute table and not the 'original' or cell by cell table.

Comment: I think it's because rasters are essentially matrices whilst you are wanting rows in a table. Two very different data constructs. Whilst your data is small enough to view in a "table format" most rasters are significantly larger and what you want is not sensible or appropriate for processing.